# I cannot sign in in Dropbox

Tags: login, dropbox

I'm using Ubuntu 22.10 with Dropbox desktop application.
It has worked normally until I decided to make a fresh reinstall of the OS to show a friend how to do it-
I have reinstalled the application and clicked on "signin". Well nothing happens.
I've tried with the installer from the Dropbox website, from the Ubuntu Store and from Flatub, with no success. After each attempt I have purged the system from Dropbox remains and restarted the pc.
I've also tried with older versions of Dropbox. Nothing...
Any idea about how to overcome this issue?

When I try to start dropbox in the terminal this is what I get.

```
    Starting Dropbox...dropbox: load fq extension '/home/trippone/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-171.4.6182/cryptography.hazmat.bindings._openssl.abi3.so'
dropbox: load fq extension '/home/trippone/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-171.4.6182/cryptography.hazmat.bindings._padding.abi3.so'
dropbox: load fq extension '/home/trippone/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-171.4.6182/apex._apex.abi3.so'
dropbox: load fq extension '/home/trippone/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-171.4.6182/psutil._psutil_linux.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
dropbox: load fq extension '/home/trippone/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-171.4.6182/psutil._psutil_posix.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
dropbox: load fq extension '/home/trippone/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-171.4.6182/tornado.speedups.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
dropbox: load fq extension '/home/trippone/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-171.4.6182/wrapt._wrappers.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
dropbox: load fq extension '/home/trippone/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-171.4.6182/PyQt5.QtCore.so'
dropbox: load fq extension '/home/trippone/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-171.4.6182/PyQt5.QtGui.so'
dropbox: load fq extension '/home/trippone/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-171.4.6182/PyQt5.QtWidgets.so'
Dropbox isn't running!
Done!
trippone@Trippone:~$ dropbox: load fq extension '/home/trippone/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-171.4.6182/PyQt5.QtDBus.so'

(dropbox:3670): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: 18:34:42.561: About to Show called on an item wihtout submenus.  We're ignoring it.
```

Thanks in advance.
Matteo

Comment: if you start the application in a terminal, do you get any errors? Or does dropbox write any logs?

Comment: No errors, let me check about logs when back home.

Comment: Are yo able to log in to your Dropbox using https://www.dropbox.com/h?role=personal in a browser? Check that you haven't used all your free licences. Click on your user icon on the Dropbox header bar to see the options available.

Comment: Dropbox works fine from my browsers and have only two linked devices. The app isn't even able to login.

Comment: Edited the initial question adding the message when trying to start Dropbox from the Terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Solved: I realized that, when updating in the terminal I received a warning messages about dropbox key "... Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring..."
While it shouldn't produce any effect (it's just a warning) according to the fonts I consulted, I solved it following:
https://itsfoss.com/key-is-stored-in-legacy-trusted-gpg/  but you can find the same instruction everywhere.
Then I run

$ dropbox start

from the terminal and received thei nvitation to link my computer to dropox as usual...

To link this computer to a Dropbox account, visit the following url:
https://www.dropbox.com/cli_link_nonce?nonce=...

Hoping it's what it has solved it.
Best!